# Did Python 3.9 update how to type hint the function type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing, python-3.9

Before 3.9 I would have used this:

```
from typing import Callable

def my_function(argument_function: Callable) -> None:
```

Now I am not sure anymore.

[PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) has a list of deprecated Typing-types that does *not* include `typing.Callable` but *does* include `collections.abc.Callable`.
So far I haven't use the collections.abs module but I wonder if `typing.Callable` might be related to `collections.abc.Callable` therefore making the `Callable` type hint deprecated, too.

I did try this:

```
def my_function(argument_function: callable) -> None:
```

And it works.

But is that really the correct way now?
Or Do I still have to import `typing.Callable`?

Comment: No, `callable` isn't a type.

Comment: If they intended to deprecate typing.Callable they would have deprecated typing.Callable. That PEP is specifically about reducing the amount of redundancy - they don't want two Callables in two different places that mean the same thing.

Comment: "And it works." What do you mean by "it works"? It certainly isn't accepted by, say, `mypy` and it is definitely not part of the specification

Comment: It works means: PyCharm doesn't give me a warning and treats "function: callable" the same way it treats "number: int" or "string: str". Also the code runs.

Comment: That doesn't mean much. The code would *run* you used anything, e.g. `def my_function(argument_function: sum) -> None:` even though `sum` isn't a valid type annotation. If you check the above with mypy, the semi-official static type checker, you'd get `error: Function "builtins.callable" is not valid as a type`... because as I stated earlier, `callable` *isn't a type*

Comment: Alright. Thanks. Just for clarification: `import typing: Callable` is still the way to go then?

Comment: Yes, and you probably should be using the fll form, `Callable[[ArgTypes], ReturnType]`

Answer (score 1):

Since there isn't an answer, I'm elevating juanpa.arrivillaga's comment to an answer. Quoting the above comment [sic]:

> you probably should be using the fll form, `Callable[[ArgTypes], ReturnType]`

Or fleshing it out:

```py
from typing import Callable

# Let's say this was an example of argument_function and that's 
# the signature that you expect in my_function

def foo(x: int) -> str:
    return str(x)

def my_function(argument_function: Callable[[int], str]) -> None:
    pass
```